# How to deal with address (like zip-code) for training a model?

Tags: machine-learning, geospatial, categorical-encoding

To me it doesn't make sense to normalize it even if it is a numerical variable like Zip Code. An address should be interpreted as categorical features like "neighborhood"... ?

Suppose I have geolocalisation data (latitude & longitude), the best thing to do seem to use k-means clustering and then working with cluster's label that I "encode".

If the answer is : "it depends" please tell me how

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. You're right it doesn't make sense to consider a zip code as numerical, let alone normalize it. But if you want a more useful answer you will need to clarify what you want to do and what kind of data you have, it's not clear.

Comment: Thanks ! Say my target variable ranks educational level in a given country, and my dataset observations provide this rank for many cities, neighborhoods (and, of course, I have the corresponding latitude & longitude position or ZipCode etc..). Hope that makes my question clear ?

Comment: It would also depend on how may different zipcodes there are in the data,  how many instances by zipcode, what is the task  (target and potentially its distribution), etc. If the zipcode is used only as geographical location and you also have the latitude/longitude you could simply remove it, it's redundant.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I don't have any specific problem I was trying to share a thought :)

Comment: I have found the answer in the book "Machine Learning Engineering" by Andriy Burkov in chapter 4.12 :)

Comment: If you found a solution, you are encouraged to answer your own question to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book "Machine Learning Engineering" by Andriy Burkov (chapter 4.12.4), it is recommended to consider "Zip Codes" as categorical like "country" would be. The goal being reducing cardinality  (i.e the number of unique values) of such variables in order to avoid "several modes" depending on that feature.